# Elasticsearch index size using different analyzers

Tags: elasticsearch

The goal is to reduce an index size.

I have several String fields, on which, I am setting an nGram analyzer from 1 character to `45 characters`. The overall index size is reached to `65GB`. Then, I removed the `nGram analyzer` from `4 fields` and repopulated the index (those 4 fields, are now using the Standard analyzer), the index reached to 70GB (even bigger).

I tried again with index: not_analyzed for those 4 fields, and the index now `reached 75.4GB`.

I am deleting and creating the index each time from the beginning.

Does anyone have a clue why?
Is there a way to know the size of the fields?

Comment: Index size depends on the analyzers and the content. Are you indexing the same documents for each attempt you're trying? What about replication options?

Comment: Same documents all the time. Taking the same static table from Oracle to Elasticsearch using logstash. I am only re-creating the index and changing the fields mapping for the tests. I would like to know, how the standard analyzer makes the index to consume more space than the nGram analyzer. I have 9 String fields, 5 must be with nGram, and I am testing what to do with the last 4 fields. Trying to save as much space as possible

Comment: I recommended you to try with sample bulks to try the configuration. The nGram analyzer varies depending on the size of the gram and the standard analyzer drops depending on the content and create tokens based on multiple conditions : special characters , spaces..